# eirslett frontend-maven-plugin failing with 403 on yarn install

Tags: java, maven, jhipster, maven-frontend-plugin

I am using eirslett frontend-maven-plugin to build war file but getting the below error:

> [ERROR] error An unexpected error occurred:
>   "http://registry.npmjs.org/calendar-utils/-/calendar-utils-0.1.2.tgz:
>   Request failed \"403 Forbidden\"".

below is the pom.xml for how I used the plugin

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install node and yarn</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                                    <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                    <nodeDownloadRoot>https://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
                                    <npmDownloadRoot>http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/</npmDownloadRoot>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>yarn install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install --force</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>webpack build test</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run webpack:test</arguments>
                                    <yarnInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>true</yarnInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>webpack build prod</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run webpack:prod</arguments>
                                    <yarnInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>true</yarnInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

I am having this problem in prod profile only

```
./mvnw -Pprod package -DskipTests
```

any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Does the faulty link works when pasted in URL bar of your browser?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou yes it works and downloads the file.

Comment: can you help me understand where should I make changes to make yarn take another registry url @GaëlMarziou

Comment: See yarn doc: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/config/ but I don't understand what you expect from it.